# How to split strings with multiple delimiters while keep the delimiters | python

Tags: python, string, split

For example, I have a string `section 213(d)-456(c)`

How can I split it to get a list of strings:

`['section', '213', '(', 'd', ')', '-', '456', '(', 'c', ')']`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so using Regex.

```py
import re
text = "section 213(d)-456(c)"
output = re.split("(\W)", text)
```

Output: `['section', ' ', '213', '(', 'd', ')', '', '-', '456', '(', 'c', ')', '']`

Here \W is for non-word character!

Answer (score 0):

You can come close with

```
re.split(r'([-\s()])', 'section 213(d)-456(c)')
```

When the delimiter contains a capture group, the result includes the captured text.

However, this will also include the space delimiters in the result:

```
['section', ' ', '213', '(', 'd', ')', '', '-', '456', '(', 'c', ')', '']
```

You can easily remove these afterward.